Proving the Plane Harmonic Oscillator move in an ellipse
My problems states that we have $r(t)$ satisfying $m\ddot{r}(t)=-kr(t)$
And in the first section we were asked to evaluate the derivative of $r(t)\times \dot{r}(t)$
And by cross product derivative law we have $$\frac d {dt} (r(t)\times \dot{r}(t))=\dot{r}(t)\times \dot{r}(t)+r(t)\times \ddot{r}(t)$$
Since collinear objects in cross product cancel out, we have $r(t)\times \ddot{r}(t)$ left.
And by applying the harmonic oscillator equation we have $r(t)\times \ddot{r}(t)=r(t)\times -\frac k m r(t)=-\frac k m r(t)\times r(t)=0$
And the next question asks us to prove that it moves in an ellipse and calculate its revolution period. I have no idea how to do that though. It seems that using this result might be helpful, but I don't know where to start.
Edit
Following the hint of @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, I obtained that
Given $(x_0,y_0)=r(0),(v_{x_0},v_{y_0})=\dot{r}(0).$ We have the solution to $$m\ddot{r}(t)=-kr(t)$$
as $$r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$$Where$$x(t)=\sqrt{x_0^2+v_{x_0}\frac mk}\sin(\sqrt{\frac km}t+\arcsin(\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{x_0^2+v_{x_0}^2\frac mk}})$$$$y(t)=\sqrt{y_0^2+v_{y_0}^2\frac mk}\sin (\sqrt{\frac km}t+\arcsin (\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{y_0^2+v_{y_0}^2\frac mk}}))$$
And my question is, how does this imply $r(t)$ is an ellipse?

can you use energy concepts? or only newtons second law?

Also, you could assume $x$ and $y$ trace an ellipse and work backwards, trying to prove that such $x$ and $y$ satisfy Newton's second law.

"Hooke's central forces" refers to the fact that the force law corresponds to the force by a linear spring. Along each component, there is a force pointing toward the origin linear in the displacement from it. If you can use the solution of the simple harmonic oscillator in 1D, the proof that the trajectory is an ellipse is trivial.

The meaning of the section title is straightforward. $m\ddot r(t) = -k r(t)$$ is Hooke's Law, named after the 17th century British scientist Robert Hooke.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I have applied your hint, but I still can't see how this is trivial.

@DavidHammen Thank you for the clarification

I have found this PDF (from which I'll just mostly copy the contents).
It starts from the solution of the equations of motion,
$$x=A\cos(\omega t+\alpha) \\ y=B\cos(\omega t + \beta).$$
It then says to eliminate the time $t$ by adding
$$y=B\cos(\omega t + \alpha + \Delta)$$
where $\Delta = \beta - \alpha$ (see how $y$ depends on $\alpha$ now). Now we can use the trig identity
$$\cos(a+b) = \cos a\cos b - \sin a\sin b$$
to obtain
$$y=B[\cos(\omega t+\alpha)\cos\Delta - \sin(\omega t+\alpha)\sin\Delta.$$
You can now put $x$ into the equation (because both $x$ and $y$ depend on $\alpha$) which yields
$$\frac{y}{B}=\frac{x}{A}\cos\Delta - \left(1-\frac{x^2}{A^2}\right)^{1/2}\sin\Delta.$$
(see $\sin=(1-\cos^2)^{1/2}$) Now transpose, square and rewrite
$$\frac{x^2}{A^2}-xy\frac{2\cos\Delta}{AB}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}=\sin^2\Delta.$$
Now this is a quadratic equation in $x$ and $y$ with the general form
$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey=f.$$
This represents an ellipse if the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ is negative. The discriminant in our case is $-(2\sin\Delta\cdot 1/(AB))$ is negative, which means that the harmonic oscillator does indeed follow the path of an ellipse. Interesting to see, if the phase difference $\Delta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ the equation reduces to
$$\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}=1,$$
which is a clearer equation for an ellipse.

As we can see, in the x-y plane, the particle describes simple harmonic motion, along two perpendicular axes (in this case, x & y axes).
Both the SHMs are in phase, having the same angular velocity about the mean, implying that their time period of oscillations are equal.
Their amplitudes may or may not be different, leading to the cases of elliptical or circular paths respecitvely.
Thus, the locus of a plane harmonic oscillator is an ellipse.
If my answer helped, do let me know.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
